# .htaccess redirect to new domain with path intact for both www and non-www as well as https and non https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

Essentially I need an .htaccess file that will redirect all traffic to our new domain. It need to work in the following conditions:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/path/file.php => http://www.newdomain.com/path/file.php
https://www.olddomain.com/path/file.php => http://www.newdomain.com/path/file.php
```

(note in the above case the https redirect to http - this is not an issue)

Also:

```
http://olddomain.com/path/file.php => http://newdomain.com/path/file.php
https://olddomain.com/path/file.php => http://newdomain.com/path/file.php
```

I've almost got it working by first redirecting the https version of www.olddomin.com to http version of `www.olddomain.com` which then redirects to the http version of the new domain, the problem I have is with the non-www version of `https://olddomain.com` which redirects to `http://olddomain.com` and then stops.

The code I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This almost works except that `https://olddomain.com/path/file.php` just redirects to `http://olddomain/path/file.php` and stops and doesn't get redirected to `http://newdomain.com/path/file.php`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need this **single rule** in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of olddomain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

**Explanation:**

- `NC` - ignore case
- `L` - Last
- `R=301` - Send `301` status to browser
- `NE` - no escaping
- `%1` - is the value we capture in first `(...)` in `RewriteCond`. That will be either `www` or blank

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar - thankyou, that worked a treat! =)

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you. This question was really interesting.

Comment: During testing it is good to use [R=302,L,NE], and only change it to [R=301,L,NE] after everything works as expected

Comment: It would be an even better answer if you commented on what the flags and modifiers did! Teach a man to fish and all that..

Comment: @anubhava I am running a wordpress. I got two domains pointing to same installation. Running your code gave me 500 error. Can you please see my code in this [tiny codeshare?](https://codeshare.io/0gnm1N). 
I almost have not changed your code. Only added one more rule which followed your rules.
Got any idea why? Thank you :pray:

Comment: @anubhava - I have posted a question describing better my problem. Thank you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70704879/how-to-redirect-two-different-domains-to-a-same-server-including-path-and-avoi