# How to redirect domains on a wordpress site, including path?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I there.

I got a website with 2 different domains pointing to itself.

1. *Domain.com*
2. *Domain.com.br*

The site loaded both domains and created duplicated content, which have created a giant problem for SEO (both domains loaded the exact same content.

I wish to resolve this problem by redirecting one domain to the other, using [301] redirection.

I want to keep *Domain.com.br* & redirect *Domain.com*. Is it possible to do that on the same server?

Till now, I have I came across 2 snippets of codes.

- First one gives me an internal server error (500).
- Second one redirected the top level domain (.com >> .com.br) but does not passed the path, meaning when you hit *domain.com/path* you still load *domain.com/path*

What do you guys think? How can I resolve that?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  // This have given me an internal server error 500
  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC, OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)?domain\.com.br$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1domain.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]


  // This one also isn't working. Only top domain is redirecting. 
  // Request URL does not pass.
  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com.br$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://domain.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

The following example, will redirect localhost >> localhost/test, but will not redirect localhost/xyz >> localhost/xyz/test

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?localhost$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:8888/test/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Any help would be super helpful. Thank you

**Problem solved**

As @anubhava mentioned, codes needs to be topmpost - first ones on the htaccess file.

All the codes I always received worked. Problem was that I placed the rewriting rules after wordpress rules. This prevented my rules to get written, cause the permalinks got written before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming both domains are pointing to same `DocumentRoot`**, you can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This rule will redirect to `.br` domain if `HTTPS` is not on OR host name in request is `domain.com` with optional `www.` before.

Make sure this is your topmost rule and you completely clear browser cache before testing.

Comment: Extremely thank you @anubhava for replying to me.
Thing is that the first example that I have pasted here, is the example that you have given in the other post. It generated 500 server error. Any idea how can that be?

Regarding DocumentRoot - yes, both of them sits on the same level. Have the pages.

Comment: No, that's not correct. Your first example code doesn't have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]` condition and reason you are getting `500` because of extra space in `[NC, OR]`. Test with just this given rule in your .htaccess and preferably from command like curl to avoid any old cache.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava again for your reply. I am running your code under a local wordpress machine. I get the redirect to work on urls like rootUrl or phpinfo.php that I have created, but pages that are blog related do not get redirected. The installation is  totally clean. No plugins at all. Does this rules can get applied on WP site? Do I need to change them in a way?

Comment: Solved the problem @anubhava. Had to place the rewriting rules before WP applied his owns. See my other comment for a reference.

Comment: I had already mentioned `Make sure this is your topmost rule` in my answer :)

Comment: Wow. You have said that. I completely lost it in the text. I guess I was so desperate that I have not seen it. Thank you. I will delete my answer and will accept yours. Thank you!